# What is the bound on $E\|Y_n\|^4$ in terms of $n$?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, asymptotics

Let $X_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be i.i.d. zero-mean random variables in some separable Hilbert space with $E\|X_n\|^8<\infty$ and $Y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_n$. I need to find bounds on $E\|Y_n\|^4$. The CLT tells me that $Y_n = O_p(n^{-1/2})$. Can I say something about $E\|Y_n\|^4$ ?

As I understand, $\|\sqrt{n}Y_n\|^4\xrightarrow{d}\|G\|^4$, where $G$ is some Gaussian process, so that $\|Y_n\|^4 = O_p(n^{-2})$, but I don't see how do deal with expected value of something bounded in probability.

Update: I did the following computations
$$\begin{aligned}
E\|Y_n\|^4 & = \frac{1}{n^4}E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\langle X_i,X_j\rangle\right)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^nE[\langle X_i,X_j\rangle\langle X_k,X_l\rangle]
\end{aligned}$$
but then it is a dissaster, to consider all cases for indices... For example, if $i\ne j\ne k\ne l$, $E[\langle X_i,X_j\rangle\langle X_k,X_l\rangle] = E[\langle X_i,X_j\rangle]E[\langle X_k,X_l\rangle]=0$ due to independence. Is there an elegant way to tackle it?

Comment: I think if you follow the characteristic function proof of the CLT, you can probably extract the information you want.

Comment: Could you give me another hint:)? I see that taking characteristic function of $\sqrt{n}Y_n$, we have $E\left[e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}\right] = \left[\phi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right]^n = \left[1 - \frac{1}{2}\frac{t^2}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]^n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2E[X^2]}$, where we do Taylor expansion and $\phi$ is a characteristic function of $X_n$, but I don't see how this can help me.

Comment: Far from being a disaster, the approach you describe in your Update is the way to go, as user @saz explains in their (at present deleted) answer.

Comment: @Did Somehow, I'm confused. My answer works fine for $H=\mathbb{R}$, but I don't see how to get rid of the mixed terms in this general setting (i.e. why is e.g. $\mathbb{E}(\langle X_i,X_j \rangle \langle X_j,X_j \rangle)=0$ for $i \neq j$?) [Might well be that I'm missing something obvious. Today, I'm failing to see a lot of things, it seems.]

Comment: @saz One is not sure that $E(\langle X_i,x\rangle\cdot\langle x,x\rangle)=0$? This seems to be simply $\langle E(X_i),x\rangle\cdot\langle x,x\rangle$, no?

Comment: @Did Ah, I see - it's just the definition of the mean of a Hilbert-space valued random variable. (I was wondering why I can interchange expectation+scalar product.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lionville No, this doesn't hold. Note that $$\mathbb{E}(\langle X,x \rangle) = \langle \mathbb{E}X,x\rangle$$ holds for any fixed ("deterministic") $x \in H$. This does not imply  $$\mathbb{E}(\langle X,Y \rangle) = \langle \mathbb{E}X,Y \rangle$$ for an $H$-valued random variable $Y$.

Comment: This is what I initially thought, but then I was confused by the @Did comment, which I guess I didn't understand correctly. Anyway, we can handle mixed terms using Fourier series expansion $X = \sum_{i\geq 0}\langle X,e_i\rangle e_i$. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: @Lionville Did's comment refered to the case when $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. In this case, we have by the tower property $$\mathbb{E}(\langle X,Y \rangle) = \mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}(\langle X,y \rangle) \big|_{y=Y}) = 0$$ as $$\mathbb{E}(\langle X,y \rangle = \langle \mathbb{E}X,y \rangle=0.$$ (That's what I used for the mixed terms in the "otherwise"-case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\mathbb{E}(\|Y_n\|^4) = \frac{1}{n^4} \sum_{j,k,l,m=1}^n \mathbb{E}(\langle X_j, X_k \rangle \langle X_l, X_m \rangle).$$

It follows from the independence of the random variables and the fact that $X_n$ has mean zero (i.e. $\mathbb{E}(\langle X_n,x \rangle)=0$ for all $x \in H$) that

$$\mathbb{E}(\langle X_j, X_k \rangle \langle X_l, X_m \rangle) \leq \begin{cases} \mathbb{E}(\|X_1\|^4) & j=k=l=m \\ \mathbb{E}(\|X_1\|^2)^2 & (j=k \neq l=m) \, \text{or} \, (j=l \neq k=m) \, \text{or} \, (j=m \neq k=l) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Consequently,

$$\mathbb{E}(\|Y_n\|^4) \leq \frac{1}{n^4} \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}(\|X_1\|^4) + \frac{3 \mathbb{E}(\|X_1\|^2)^2}{n^4} \sum_{j=1}^n (n-1) = O(n^{-2}).$$

Comment: Do you use Cauchy-Schwartz for $j=l\ne k=m$ case? What dots in "or..." represent?

Comment: @Lionville Yes, we have to use CS in some cases (e.g. if $j=l \neq k=m$.)

Comment: @Lionville Where do you think I use this? (it's wrong.)